# Create subdomains in staging azure web role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-roles

I have a solution with two projects:
- Project1 is an asp.net mvc 4 project
- Project2 is an asp.net webapi project

I want to have both of them on the same webrole, in production it seems that I can do the following:

- all requests going to mydomain.com will go to MVC project
- all requests goign to api.mydomain.com will go to webapi project

In staging the base url is something like ec3abfacbfb27a1800f6bc0f2b168121.cloudapp.net, is there a way to do this:

- all requests going to ec3abfacbfb27a1800f6bc0f2b168121.cloudapp.net will go to MVC project
- all requests goign to api.ec3abfacbfb27a1800f6bc0f2b168121.cloudapp.net will go to webapi project

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
And in your particular scenario (as well as many more) I would suggest to not use staging environment at all. Use another production environment instead. And name it `[myapp-stating].cloudapp.net` for example.

Than create a mapping with your own custom domain (say it is `myapp.com`):

- `staging.web.myapp.com` -> CNAME -> `myapp-staging.cloudapp.net`
- `staging.api.myapp.com` -> CNAME -> `myapp-staging.cloudapp.net`

Answer (score 0):

First, set up the routing within your web app, if you haven't already. It should look for the `api` prefix on the host name, but otherwise be independent the URL.

Then for manual testing with a browser, edit `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add a line for `api.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.cloudapp.net`, using your staging server's IP address.

For automated testing, have the test client connect to the staging server using its regular host name (without the `api` prefix) but set the `Host` header to include the `api` prefix as desired.